# CSS: creating non-equal margins when centering a block element

Tags: css, html, layout, alignment

The problem is as following. I have a block element, say `<div>` tag, and I want to center it. I can just set `margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto` and the problem will be solved. But how can I make, for example, right margin twice larger than left?

In days of yore, in HTML4.01 with frames, I could set middle frame width to 600px, left frame width to '1*' and right frame width to '2*' to get the layout I want. So how do I do the same with HTML5?

Comment: That's not exactly centering it then, is it?

Comment: margin-left: 25%; - have you tried this?

Comment: @BoltClock, no, it's not. I was just trying to explain what I want to get.

Comment: @user466764, yes, I have. This makes left margin equal to 25% of parent's width with no dependence on the right margin and the element's width.

Comment: @MattCoughlin, I think @cimmanon's solution with `display: table-cell` is pretty nice. If this is not what CSS was designed for, then what should I use? I'm sure I should **not** use JavaScript for handling such layout things.

Comment: @TigranSaluev: Sorry, after I noticed cimmanon's table solution, I went back and deleted my comment. The table solution is quite reasonable, and I'd use that (if editing the HTML is an option). If the only CSS solution were something like Flexbox (which would be ridiculous overkill in this case, albeit a very creative workaround), I'd use JavaScript (to keep the code simple and stable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a great solution as it requires Flexbox and one extra element, but the right "margin" is twice as large as the left "margin":

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/agFzw

```
.foo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  /* fix for old Firefox */
  width: 100%;
}

.bar {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 600px;
  /* optional */
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 600px;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 600px;
  flex: 0 1 600px;
}

.foo:after {
  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
  -moz-box-flex: 2;
  -webkit-flex: 2;
  -ms-flex: 2;
  flex: 2;
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
}

.foo:before {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
}    

<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    Bar
  </div>
</div>
```

http://caniuse.com/flexbox

If you're ok with 3 extra elements, you can use `display: table/table-cell` and maximize your browser support:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/saojg66o

```
.foo {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.a, .b, .c {
  display: table-cell;
}

.a {
  width: 10%;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 600px;
}

.c {
  width: 20%;
}

<div class="foo">
  <div class="a">
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Foo
  </div>
  <div class="c">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know `table-cell` works like that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to give the `div` a % width, it's very easy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

div {width: 40%; height: 600px; background: red; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 40%;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not the thing. If you set `margin-left` to `50%` and `margin-right` to `25%`, the element's left side will always be at the middle of it's parent (50% by x axis, yes). At least my Firefox doesn't even try to make such margins proportional.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. My code does exactly what you asked for, though perhaps not in the way you wanted it to. If you want a fixed width on the div, you might need JS to calculate the margins dynamically.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I forgot to say that. The element's width is fixed.

Comment: OK, I added another answer (rather than update this answer.) It's a simple attempt to do this with JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; height: 300px;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px; margin-left: -150px;
    border: 1px solid black 
}
```

This will centralize the `<div>` you said. If you want more or less margin left or right, just change `margin-left: -150px;` value.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/DeXu2/)

Comment: That won't ensure that the left margin is half of the right margin, though. As soon as the browser width changes,  the margins won't stay proportional, which seems to be the requirement here.

Answer (score 0):

Since the div must have a fixed width, JS is probably needed for achieving this. I'm new to JS, so this is probably lousy code, but it seems to do the job, anyhow: http://cdpn.io/LIizc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
div {width: 600px; height: 600px; background: red; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="test"></div>

<script>
function resize(elem){
  var windowWidth  = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
      remainder = windowWidth - elem.clientWidth;
  elem.style.marginLeft = remainder * 1/3 + "px";
}

var div = document.getElementById("test");
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  resize(div);
}, false);
resize(div);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```